# Kullback-Liebler divergence

Tags: probability

The Kullback-Liebler divergence between two distributions with pdfs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is defined
by
$$\mathrm{KL}(F;G) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)f(x)\,dx$$

Compute the Kullback-Lieber divergence when $F$ is the standard normal distribution and $G$
is the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$. For what value of $\mu$ is the divergence
minimized?

I was never instructed on this kind of divergence so I am a bit lost on how to solve this kind of integral.  I get that I can simplify my two normal equations in the natural log but my guess is that I should wait until after I take the integral. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Leibler*. // For what value of *what* is the divergence minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf of the standard normal distribution is $
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^{2}/2}$. Similarly, $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(x-\mu)^2/2}$.Therefore, $D_{KL}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{{2\mu-\mu}^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^{2}/2} dx$. This is equivalent to $\frac{{\mu}^2}{2}$.

This can be easily generalized to any two normal distributions with means $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and variances ${\sigma_1}^2, {\sigma_1}^2$.

The K-L divergence is obviously minimized at $\mu=0$ - where the distributions are the same!

EDIT: Sorry, I misread the mean as 1 originally - I have corrected it.

Comment: Wouldn't the two $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ cancel within the ln?  Also, sorry I forgot that I left out a mu for the mean on the normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, they cancel but you get another $2\pi$ from the $f(x)$. I misread your original question as mean and variance both as 1, sorry - I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment (not enough reputation).

Vincent: You have the wrong pdf for $g(x)$, you have a normal distribution with mean 1 and variance 1, not mean $\mu$.

Hint: You don't need to solve any integrals. You should be able to write this as pdf's and their expected values, so you never need to integrate.

Outline: Firstly, $ \log({f(x) \over g(x) })=\left\{ -{1 \over 2} \left( x^2 - (x-\mu )^2  \right) \right\} $ . Expand and simplify. Don't even write out the other $f(x)$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been searching for ages for the Kullback-Liebler divergence between two Normal distributions and didn't find it, but RS's answer enabled me to calculate it quite simply. Here's my derivation. I've also derived it for Beta distributions.

## Kullback-Liebler divergence of Normal Distributions

Suppose we have two Normal distributions $F\sim N(\mu_{f},\sigma_{f})$;
$G\sim N(\mu_{g},\sigma_{g})$. The Kullback-Liebler divergence is
defined as:

$$
\mathrm{KL}(F||G)=\int f(x)\ln\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)dx\quad\mathrm{nats}
$$

Divide by $\ln(2)$ to get the answer in bits. The Gaussian PDF is:

$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma_{f}\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{\dfrac{-(x-\mu_{f})^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}}
$$

Substituting we get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{KL}(F||G) & = & \int f(x)\ln\left(\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{f})^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}}}{\sigma_{f}\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sigma_{g}\sqrt{2\pi}}{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{g})^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}}}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int f(x)\ln\left(\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{f})^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}}}{\sigma_{f}}\frac{\sigma_{g}}{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{g})^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}}}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int f(x)\left[\ln\left(\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{f})^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}}}{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu_{g})^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}}}\right)+\ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)\right]dx\\
 & = & \int f(x)\left[\frac{-(x-\mu_{f})^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{-(x-\mu_{g})^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}+\ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)\right]dx
\end{eqnarray*}

Then via a tedious and error-prone but straightforward expansion we
get

$$
=\left[\ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)+\frac{-\mu_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{-\mu_{g}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]\int f(x)dx+\left[\frac{2\mu_{f}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{2\mu_{g}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]\int x\, f(x)dx+\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{-1}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]\int x^{2}f(x)dx
$$

Then we have the following properties:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int f(x)dx & = & 1\\
\int x\, f(x)dx & = & \mu_{f}\\
\int x^{2}f(x)dx & = & \mu_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{f}^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Which gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{KL}(F||G) & = & \left[\ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)+\frac{-\mu_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{-\mu_{g}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]+\left[\frac{2\mu_{f}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{2\mu_{g}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]\mu_{f}+\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}-\frac{-1}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\right]\left(\mu_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{f}^{2}\right)\\
 & = & \ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)+\frac{-\mu_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}+\frac{\mu_{g}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}+\frac{2\mu_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}+\frac{-2\mu_{g}\mu_{f}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}+\frac{-\mu_{f}^{2}-\sigma_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}+\frac{\mu_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}\\
 & = & \ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)+\frac{\mu_{g}^{2}-2\mu_{g}\mu_{f}+\mu_{f}^{2}+\sigma_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}+\frac{-\mu_{f}^{2}+2\mu_{f}^{2}-\mu_{f}^{2}-\sigma_{f}^{2}}{2\sigma_{f}^{2}}\\
 & = & \ln\left(\frac{\sigma_{g}}{\sigma_{f}}\right)+\frac{(\mu_{f}-\mu_{g})^{2}+\sigma_{f}^{2}-\sigma_{g}^{2}}{2\sigma_{g}^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

I verified this numerically in Matlab, after fixing many sign errors! If anyone wants to do this for the Beta distribution I'd be greatful!

## Kullback-Liebler divergence of Beta Distributions

Suppose we have two Beta distributions $F\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha_{f},\beta_{f})$;
$G\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha_{g},\beta_{g})$. The Kullback-Liebler
divergence is defined as:

$$\mathrm{KL}(F||G)=\int f(x)\ln\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)dx\quad\mathrm{nats}$$

Divide by $\ln(2)$ to get the answer in bits. The Beta PDF is:

$$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}x^{\alpha_{f}-1}(1-x)^{\beta_{f}-1}$$

Where $\Gamma()$ is the Gamma function. Substituting gives:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{KL}(F||G) & = & \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ln\left(\frac{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}x^{\alpha_{f}-1}(1-x)^{\beta_{f}-1}}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}x^{\alpha_{g}-1}(1-x)^{\beta_{g}-1}}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ln\left(\frac{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}x^{\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g}}(1-x)^{\beta_{f}-\beta_{g}}}{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}x^{\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g}}(1-x)^{\beta_{f}-\beta_{g}}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\left[\ln\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}+\ln\left(x^{\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g}}\right)+\ln\left((1-x)^{\beta_{f}-\beta_{g}}\right)\right]dx\\
 & = & \ln\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}+(\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g})\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ln x\, dx+(\beta_{f}-\beta_{g})\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ln(1-x)dx
\end{eqnarray*}

In terms of expectations this is:

$$\ln\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}+(\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g})\mathrm{E}\left(\ln F\right)+(\beta_{f}-\beta_{g})\mathrm{E}\left(\ln(1-F)\right)$$

From Wikipedia we have:

$$\mathrm{E}(\ln F)=\psi(\alpha_{f})-\psi(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})$$

Where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$
is the digamma function (also known as the polygamma function; it
is \texttt{psi} in Matlab). By swapping variables it is easy to show
that

$$\mathrm{E}(\ln(1-F))=\psi(\beta_{f})-\psi(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})$$

Therefore the final solution is

$$\mathrm{KL}(F||G)=\ln\frac{\Gamma(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\Gamma(\alpha_{g})\Gamma(\beta_{g})}{\Gamma(\alpha_{g}+\beta_{g})\Gamma(\alpha_{f})\Gamma(\beta_{f})}+(\alpha_{f}-\alpha_{g})\left(\psi(\alpha_{f})-\psi(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\right)+(\beta_{f}-\beta_{g})\left(\psi(\beta_{f})-\psi(\alpha_{f}+\beta_{f})\right)$$